# How to set the database name in the connection string with Entity Framework 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

So I have Solution with two projects. The first projects should act as a `Data Access Layer` so there in the `app.config` file I have this:

```
<connectionStrings>
 <add name="BloggingContextCF" 
   connectionString="provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
   provider connection string=&quot;
   data source=*****\SQLEXPRESS;
   initial catalog=CodeFirst.Blogging;
   integrated security=True;
   MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
   App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
   providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

The second Project is a `ASP.NET Web Forms` project, where I removed the default connection string pointing to the `(local)` instance leaveing only one connection string, the one from the first `Data Access Layer` project. Which actually works and the database is created on my `SQL 2008 R2` server, but instead of the desired (and expected) database name - `CodeFirst.Blogging` the name is `DataAccessLayer.BloggingContextCF` where `DataAccessLayer` is the name of the project and `BloggingContextCF` is the class extending `DbContext`.

What I need to change in my connection string so I can get the desired name?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public BloggingContextCF ():base("CodeFirst.Blogging") {}
```

Comment: Hi. Your suggestion works. But I really do want the name to be taken from the connection string and to be hardcoded in the source coude. Any idea how can I do that>

Comment: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-in-code-first.aspx   .. but this is more or less just telling you what Ashish Rajput wrote

Comment: Just one thing that I can not understand why in two of the three examples we use constructor - `public Context() : base...` and in the case that I'm asking (fetching the name from the Conn string) the code is different: `public class Context: DbContext 
    {
        public SchoolDBContext() : base("SchoolDBConnectionString") `

Answer (score 0):

make the connections string like

Point it to sql client

```
providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"
```

to

```
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

For full connection string do it like

```
<add name="BloggingContextCF" connectionString="Server=YOUR_SERVER;Database=DATABASE_NAME;User ID=USER_ID;Password=PASSWORD;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

For more connectionstring example [follow the link](http://www.connectionstrings.com/store-connection-string-in-webconfig/)

and don't forget to modify your dbcontext

```
public class YourContext : DbContext
{
    public UsersContext()
        : base("BloggingContextCF"){ }
}
```

Comment: Hi. I would like the name to be fetched from the connection string but with my connection string, and with the that you suggested When in my class which is extending `DbContext` I put `public BloggingContextCF() : base("BloggingContextCF") { }` My DB name is always like the text from `base("...")`.